# Conditional inclusion: integer constant expression is limited?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive, constant-expression

C11, 6.10.1 Conditional inclusion, Constraints, 1 (emphasis added):

> The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be an *integer constant expression*

C11, 6.6 Constant expressions, 6 (emphasis added):

> An *integer constant expression*<sup>117)</sup> shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts.

```
$ cat t333.c
#if (int)1.0
#endif

$ gcc t333.c -std=c11 -pedantic -c
t333.c:1:10: error: missing binary operator before token "1.0"
    1 | #if (int)1.0
```

Here `(int)1.0` in the integer constant expression. It has integer type and has operand, which is floating constant that is the immediate operand of cast. However, per `gcc` the code is invalid.

Meaning that "integer constant expression" used in 6.10 Preprocessing directives is limited [1]? Is it explicitly specified in the standard?

[1] For example, "except `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to look at 6.10.1p1 in its entirety:

> The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be an integer
> constant expression **except that: identifiers (including those
> lexically identical to keywords) are interpreted as described
> below**;<sup>166)</sup>, and it may contain unary operator expressions
> of the form
>
> ```
> defined identifier
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> defined ( identifier )
> ```
>
> which evaluate to 1 if the identifier is currently defined as a macro
> name (that is, if it is predefined or if it has been the subject of a
> `#define` preprocessing directive without an intervening `#undef`
> directive with the same subject identifier), 0 if it is not.

Where footnote 166 states:

> 166. Because the controlling constant expression is evaluated during
>      translation phase 4, all identifiers either are or are not macro names
>      — there simply are no keywords, enumeration constants, etc.

So the keyword `int` is not treated as a keyword by the preprocessor but instead as an identifier and therefore a macro name.  This results in invalid syntax that causes an error.

This means that integer constant expressions that involve either a cast, `sizeof`, or `_Alignof` are not allowed in an `#if` directive.

Comment: What about C++: `echo "#if 1.0" | g++ -xc++ - -std=c++11 -pedantic -c` leads to `error: floating constant in preprocessor expression`, however, I cannot see where C++ standard prohibits using floating-point literal in the expression that controls conditional inclusion. Does it prohibit? Where?

Comment: @pmor Although your question relates to language which inherits many these features from C, it's has a completely different stardard document. You should ask completely new question for it.

Comment: @user694733 Indeed. [Asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70943108/1778275).