# Conditional inclusion: integral constant expression is unlimited?

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-lawyer, constant-expression

Per C++11 (and newer) this code is valid:

```
#if 1.0 > 2.0 ? 1 : 0
#endif
```

However, most (if not all) C++ compilers reject it:

```
$ echo "#if 1.0 > 2.0 ? 1 : 0" | g++ -xc++ - -std=c++11 -pedantic -c
<stdin>:1:5: error: floating constant in preprocessor expression
<stdin>:1:11: error: floating constant in preprocessor expression
```

N4849 has this (emphasis added):

> The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be an **integral constant expression** except that identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are interpreted as described below143 and it may contain zero or more defined-macro-expressions and/or has-include-expressions and/or has-attribute-expressions as unary operator expressions.

and this (emphasis added):

> An **integral constant expression** is an expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type, implicitly converted to a prvalue, where the converted expression is a core constant expression.

The `1.0 > 2.0 ? 1 : 0` is integral constant expression.

So, where C++ standard prohibits using floating-point literal (for example) in the expression that controls conditional inclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from Richard Smith:

> This is an error in the standard wording. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1436 for details and a proposed fix -- though that fix is known to be wrong too (it permits lambda-expressions).