# What kinds of expressions are allowed in a `#if` (the conditional inclusion preprocesssor directives)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor

Many sources online (for example, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional#Condition_evaluation) say that the expression need only be an integer constant expression.

The following are all integral constant expressions without any identifiers in them:

```cpp
#include <compare>

#if (1 <=> 2) > 0
#error 1 > 2
#endif

#if (([]{}()), 0)
#error 0
#endif

#if 1.2 < 0.0
#error 1.2 < 0.0
#endif

#if ""[0]
#error null terminator is true
#endif

#if *""
#error null terminator is true
#endif
```

Yet they fail to compile with clang or gcc, so there obviously are some limitations.

The grammar for the `#if` directive is given in [cpp.pre] in the standard as:

> *if-group*:
> `#` `if` *constant-expression* *new-line* *group*<sub>opt</sub>

All of the previous expressions fit the grammar of constant-expression.

It goes on later to say (in [cpp.cond]):

> 1/
> The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be an integral constant expression except that identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are interpreted as described below

> 8/
> Each preprocessing token that remains (in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling expression) after all macro replacements have occurred shall be in the lexical form of a token.

All of the preprocessing tokens seem to be in the form of [lex.token]:

> *token*:
> *identifier*
> *keyword*
> *literal*
> *operator-or-punctuator*

`<=>`, `>`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `},` `(`, `)`, `*` are all an *operator-or-punctuator*

`1`, `2`, `0`, `1.2`, `0.0`, `""` are all literals

So what part of the standard rules out these forms of expressions? And what subset of integral constant expressions are allowed?

Comment: Dup of [Conditional inclusion: integral constant expression is unlimited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70943108/conditional-inclusion-integral-constant-expression-is-unlimited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that all of these examples are intended to be ill-formed, although as you demonstrate the current standard wording doesn't have that effect.

This seems to be tracked as active [CWG issue 1436](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1436). The proposed resolution would disqualify string literals, floating point literals and also `<=>`  from `#if` conditions. (Although `<=>` was added to the language after the issue description was written.) I suppose it is also meant to disallow lambdas, but that may not be covered by the proposed wording.